# PHP regex extract url with pattern from string

Tags: php, regex

I have got many topics on extracting all urls from a string and detecting urls with specific pattern. But not both. Sorry I am a bit rough in regex. Can someone please help.

Here is what I want:

```
$str = <<<EOF
  This string is valid - http://example.com/products/1
  This string is not valid - http://example.com/order/1
EOF;
```

Basically I want to extract all urls inside the `$str` variable which has a patter with `/products/`

I tried this for the url extraction - `/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i` but along with this I only want those having that pattern and not the others.

Comment: You are not matching `/products/` so you could add it right? `\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*\/products\/[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]`

Comment: Yes, but it only extracts a single character after the match. So, if my string is `http://example.com/products/1/abc` it just pulls upto the `1` and not the entire url.

Comment: Then you can add the optional character class after it as well `\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*\/products\/[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]` https://regex101.com/r/KatX8u/1

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat all the allowed characters before and after matching `/products/` using the same optional character class. As the character class is quite long, you could shorten the notation by wrapping it in a capture group and recurse the first subpattern as `(?1)`

Note that you don't have to escape the forward slash using a different separator.

```
$re = '`\b(?:(?:https?|ftp)://|www\.)([-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*)/products/(?1)[-a-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]`';

$str = <<<EOF
  http://example.com/products/1/abc
  This string is valid - http://example.com/products/1
  This string is not valid - http://example.com/order/1
EOF;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/products/1/abc
    [1] => http://example.com/products/1
)
```

Comment: I am not sure about this particular option @The fourth bird. I tried this. It pulls the urls correct, but does not extract them whole. Am I doing something wrong here - https://regex101.com/r/z06ETA/1 ?

Comment: @PratipGhosh It matches the same as the full pattern that is in the comments. See https://3v4l.org/iACY8

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answer from "The fourth bird" I am proposing another hybrid solution which is using both regex and classic string operations to provide a helper function with some additional options e.g. to get different results in runtime without changing the RE

```
<?php

function GetURL($str, $pattern='/products/')
{
    $temp = array();
    preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $str, $match);
    foreach ($match[0] as $link)
    {
        if(!$pattern)
            array_push($temp, $link);
        else if(strpos($link, $pattern) !== false)
            array_push($temp, $link);
    }
    return $temp;
}

$str = <<<EOF
  This string is valid - http://example.com/products/1
  This string is not valid - http://example.com/order/1
EOF;

print_r(GetURL($str)); //Urls only with /products/ inside
print_r(GetURL($str, '/order/')); //Urls only with /order/ inside
print_r(GetURL($str, false)); //All urls

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => http://example.com/products/1 ) 
Array ( [0] => http://example.com/order/1 ) 
Array ( 
   [0] => http://example.com/products/1 
   [1] => http://example.com/order/1 
)
```